# Changing parameters in real time

Tags: video, video-streaming, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I am running a pipeline with `Gstreamer`.

Is there a way to change the parameters of `application/x-rtp` in real time?

For example- 
the "play-speed" field.

Maybe with events? I couldn't understand how.

**edit:**

the main problem is using the seek event with "pcapparse". when I load mp4 file, the seek event works great.

but when I load pcap file, nothing happens on seek event.

those are the two pipelines:

```
data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("filesrc name=my_filesrc ! queue ! decodebin2 ! 
autovideosink", NULL);

data.pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("filesrc name=my_filesrc  ! queue  ! pcapparse 
caps=\"application/x-rtp, payload=(int)96, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, 
encoding-name=(string)H264, **play-speed=2.0**\"  ! queue  ! gstrtpjitterbuffer latency=100 
! decodebin2 ! autovideosink", NULL);
```

I found that I can control the video speed with "play-speed" on "application/x-rtp".
but the problem is that I have to set it before I hit the play button- not in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you send a seek, that changes the play-back speed to the pipeline, the that has "application/x-rtp" caps will renegotiate them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, as you can see after I edited the post, Im kind of stuck, the seek event doesnt effect the pipeline if I load pcap file. I dont know where is the problem..

Comment: pcapparse will as far as I know just replay a captured stream. It might now be able to alter (some) parameters. Anyway this would be easier to discuss in the developer IRC channel.